# Occasionally getting null body in APIGatewayProxyEvent for requests with binary data as the body

Tags: file, request, null, react-hook-form, gateway

I have a form webapp, utilizing React and react-hook-form. There is a file input in the form that take image attachments, specifically jpeg and png. I am sending these via HTTP Request to an AWS API Gateway resource, called /images.

request:

```
await fetch(api.host.name/images, {
    {
        'Content-type': contentType //ie. image/jpeg
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: image //File object from react-hook-form <image input field>.value
}...
```

handler (nodejs Lambda):

```
const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(event.body, 'base64');
```

The issue I am having is that for some requests, I get the error that the first argument of Buffer.from() is null. This is in production and only happening on requests from Chrome/Edge. There are also many successful Chrome/Edge submissions.